# Sending in String vs Reading String

Tags: python, string, file, io

I have a text file that contains something like:

```
IP_ADD = "10.10.150.3"
BACKUP_IP = "10.10.150.4"
```

and the code to read it in:

```
counter = 0
wordList = [None] * 100

with open("config.txt") as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()

for line in content:
    line = line.split(' ',2)[-1]
    wordList[counter] = line
    counter = counter + 1
```

which will return to me just the IP Address with the quotes inside wordList.. IE

```
wordList[0] = "10.10.150.3"
```

I then try to send an SNMP command using the OID and that IP address. IE

```
agent.set(MY_OID,wordList[0])
```

but this doesnt work. If I change it to the following:

```
agent.set(MY_OID,"10.10.150.3")
```

it works. What am I missing here?

Comment: Side note: There is no need to read the entire file with `f.read()` then split that and then loop over the lines. Just do: `for line in f:` and loop over each line as it is read from the file. More Pythonic...

Comment: Second side note: Don't create an empty list using `wordList = [None] * 100` Just use `word_list=[]` at the top and then use `word_list.append(new_thing)` to add to the list. That eliminates the need for the `counter` as well. If do need a counter, use `enumerate` and the initiation and incrementing is automatic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, you just need to strip the double quotes around your IPs. Use `strip('"')` to do that.

```
line.split(' ',2)[-1].strip('"')
```

---

Your code seems too shabby, no offence. You are doing things many of which are not necessary. You can do it much simply this way:

```
wordList = []
with open('config.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        wordList.append(line.split()[-1].strip('"'))

print(wordList)
```

Output:

```
['10.10.150.3', '10.10.150.4']
```

Answer (score 3):

From what you wrote it appears that your file has the IP addr in quotes.
Hence

```
 line = line.split(' ',2)[-1]
```

will return an IP address in quotes as a string, aka

```
 "\"10.0.0.1\""
```

This is what you are sending across the wire, which is probably not what you intend to do.